# Running local dynamodb (docker) using Maven plugin io.fabric8

Tags: java, docker, maven, amazon-dynamodb

Using Maven I want to start local dynamodb (using docker) before IT (Integration Test) and stop it after IT is done.

I can see that the server start (I am looking at Docker Desktop and I see that the container is alive).

However the IT code can not connect to the server.
Relevant code fragments below:
Maven:

```
   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${failsafe.jacoco.args}</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.42.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-dynamodb-local</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <images>
                            <image>
                                <name>amazon/dynamodb-local</name>
                                <alias>dynamodb-local</alias>
                                <run>
                                    <ports>
                                        <port>1234:1234</port>
                                    </ports>
                                    <wait>
                                        <log>Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:</log>
                                        <time>1000</time>
                                    </wait>
                                </run>
                            </image>
                        </images>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-dynamodb-local</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <images>
                            <image>
                                <name>amazon/dynamodb-local</name>
                                <alias>dynamodb-local</alias>
                            </image>
                        </images>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Java Code:

```
    System.out.println(String.format("DynamoDB url: %s", dynamoURL));
    AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfig = new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(dynamoURL,null);
    AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfig)
            .build();
```

The code prints `DynamoDB url: http://127.0.0.1:1234`
The exception is:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The target server failed to respond
        at com.p81.delta.gw.DynamoDBPersistenceManagerIT.createTable(DynamoDBPersistenceManagerIT.java:48)
        at com.p81.delta.gw.DynamoDBPersistenceManagerIT.before(DynamoDBPersistenceManagerIT.java:37)
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
        at com.p81.delta.gw.DynamoDBPersistenceManagerIT.createTable(DynamoDBPersistenceManagerIT.java:48)
        at com.p81.delta.gw.DynamoDBPersistenceManagerIT.before(DynamoDBPersistenceManagerIT.java:37)
```

Any idea what the Java code fail to connect to the local dynamodb?

thanks

### Update

Changing the port from 1234 to 8000 solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't defined a custom port for DynamoDB it defaults to port `8000`:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: But it could not work with port 1234?

Comment: What command did you use to start it on port 1234?

Comment: see pom.xml above